# 3531 Duplicate Symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

App run successfully on simulator when connected device trying to run application, got following error.

**ld: 3531 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Assuming duplicate framework added.

Here is my pod file

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.6'
pod 'FlexibleGauge', '~> 0.1'
```

No more extra framework added in project.

I have no clue why its happening like this.
Please let me know your inputs for the duplicate symbols error message.

Comment: @matt why I get negative not understand! To the digital Question do have lot of multiple answers. not easy to navigate for correct one!

Answer (score 1):

**Modify the version of these :**

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.11'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
```

Be sure to have the version

Comment: No its does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Find out why its like this!

I had another X-code 10 beta. When run with beta version got this error.
The same project try to open in X-Code 10. Then try to run the application in device bingo.  Its just worked.